# Is there evidence of concrete Meta contribution to the rules that govern ELU?

Tags: discussion, meta

This is a nice place for giving  vent to our frustrations, to express our best thoughts on how to improve the site  and to suggest the  improvements  we would sincerely like to see implemented to make ELU a "better" place.

But has any of the ideas put forward so far  really made a concrete change to the main site? Is there any evidence of effective implementations?  and which would the procedure that a suggestion should follow to be finally materialised  in a real change?

P.S. I am referring to changes in the written rules, those which we refer to in the help center.

Comment: Well, one such contribution was the question limit. But finding the relevant Meta posts for that, let alone others, would take some time.

Comment: Not to mention the changes in close reasons. There must be others.

Comment: I think it would be useful to have a list of the changes and the improvements   achieved. It may serve as a guideline to users.

Comment: Sure there are some venting questions here, but lots of practical changes, huge and tiny, have come about. The existence of ELL came about through questions here; lots of individual close/open issues on individual questions/answers are discussed and acted on. Also meta is not necessarily just for making 'concrete changes to the main site'. DIcussion and understanding contribute to subtle behavioral changes

Comment: In order to make ELU a "better" place, we should stop answering a general reference question, for example, it takes us 5 minutes to find an answer, and it takes five minutes for the OP to find the same answer. We are not a dictionary service.

Comment: @Rathony - yes, all off-topic activities should be avoided, but my question is about a different issue.

Comment: @Mitch - I agree this site  plays  an important role  with respect to discussions about behavioural issues, but what  is less evident, al least to me, is the real impact on rules that govern this site.

Comment: 'My question is about a different issue': can you elaborate? 'The real impact on rules':  the 'rules' are either built in to SE (where we can make feature requests) or user behavior (discussion). What is the problem you're asking about and what is your suggested fix?

Comment: @Mitch - I am referring to changes (possibly  improvements) in the  rules that can be found  in the help center. Andrew Leach appears to have perfectly understood the question. I am not referring to behavioural issues.

Comment: The first thing that comes to mind was the change in the help center and addition of the site tour. I can't remember when those things were implemented, but I do remember my subjective impression that we had far fewer users who expressed frustration at not being able to find things. There were also changes to the top nav and the way hot network questions are displayed. We've also had content changes in the help center itself. This is a good question -- I wish I knew how to answer it.